# What limitations of generative grammar was Lakoff referring to?

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar, chomsky

In his keynote address in 2015, [George Lakoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lakoff) said the [following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuUnMCq-ARQ&t=22m10s) (at 22:10)

> The whole idea of generative grammar fell apart. There were things that you could not do with it. Even if it was meaningless, you still couldn't do certain sentences... There are examples where there can't be a deep structure, for example. That was discovered in '74, and nobody's found a way to do it since then.

I find this confusing. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_grammar)

> Generative Grammar considers grammar as a system of rules that generates exactly those combinations of words that form grammatical sentences in a given language.

Since the rules are arbitrary, shouldn't we be able to encode essentially anything with them?

So my question is: what are the limitations of generative grammar, and specifically what is Lakoff referring to here?

Comment: Is your question about generative grammar, or about Lakoff's opinion about GG?

Comment: @user6726 He seems to be talking about facts ("discovered", "cannot do"), not just opinions ("like" / "dislike")

Comment: Does the answer crucially have to refer to anything that Lakoff said, or can we just ignore his speech?

Comment: @user6726 If you know that some limitations of GG were discovered in '74, I'd say you can ignore his speech. If you don't, you should probably be asking the same Q I just did.

Comment: So you are looking for evidence to support the claim that there are limitations on GG, and not asking if it is true.

Comment: @user6726 I wouldn't say that. I just think that if an SE anon (no offense) is going to contradict a highly respected authority on the topic, he should at least know (or want to know) what that authority was referring to.

Comment: Maybe jlawler can represent Lakoff's position: I oppose it.

Comment: George and I have always had the agreement that he's not responsible for what I say and I'm not responsible for what he says. Though I don't agree with this particular chunk, taken out of context. When he says _There were things that you could not do with it_ he's not talking about most of the things linguists would want to to. Note that for about the last 20 years or so, he's billed himself as a cognitive scientist rather than a linguist.